# Explore matrix for adjacent duplicates (find connections)

Tags: javascript

I am making a [folt](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/folt/id823039529?mt=8) clone for fun and I am having trouble with the explore function. Basically I want to reset grid locations when the connected tiles > 3. Here is an example of what might happen during the game...

```
current_position=[3,4]
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 2 2 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 3 

move(down)
current_position=[4,4]
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 2 2 0 
0 0 0 1 2 0 
0 0 0 1 2 3 

resetGridLocations(explore([4,4]))
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 0 
0 0 0 1 0 3 

score += 3
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ladicolazo/1/edit?html,console) is a JS bin of my source code for the game. You can play the semi-functional version by calling `move(keyCode)` in the console. Currently the explore() function searches 2 layers around the position for duplicate values. It works for the above example but not for larger groups like below. A recursive solution seems attractive.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 2 0 
0 0 1 1 2 0 
0 0 0 2 2 0 
0 0 0 1 2 0 
0 0 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: Can it happen that there are more then one group of adjacent tiles with the same number? Do the adjacent tiles need to be in a row or not? What's the expected output for your last example?

Comment: So if the last move was [4,3] then all connected 2's should be reset. So only 1 group at a time. If the tile is above below or on either side it is considered "connected"

Comment: I think you're looking for a [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) then.

Comment: Yes that looks like what I want. Thank you!